Compiled with MSYS2 but DLL not found running in CMD
I am building a pure C project with make in MSYS2 on a Windows box.  The resulting executable runs just fine at the MSYS2 prompt, but when using CMD it fails because it cannot find libpq.dll (my code is talking to a postgres DB).
I installed postgres on MSYS2 using pacman, so it is installed in the usual place.  The code compiles without any warnings (and I have enabled a lot of warnings), and runs properly on MSYS2, so I am confident that the code is correct.  It is the build that is problematic.
For what reasons might the executable be unable to find a DLL when called using CMD even though it works at the MSYS prompt?  What can I do to investigate and/or solve this?
Edit:
A user has kindly pointed out that this question is very similar to this one.  I understand that my problem is probably related to an environment variable that can be altered, or perhaps copying the MSYS2 dll to a particular place, but I have little experience with Windows, and would appreciate guidance with this.

Compare the PATH between the environment where it works and the one where it doesn't.

This question is similar to: DLL search on windows. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Many thanks @CharlesDuffy.  I certainly see the relevance of that question to my own, but I'm afraid my lack of experience with Windows systems makes it very hard for me to understand how to apply those answers to my own situation.  I suspect that there is an environment variable that I need to edit, and/or that I need to copy the libpg dll to another location, but other than that I am afraid that I am at a loss.  I hope for your patience with my lack of expertise.

Is your application using the same bitsize as the Postgres?  compiled for 64bit?  Worth a quick check

If it is a PATH problem, you can work around it either by adjusting the PATH to have whichever entry points to a directory with the DLL, or by copying the DLL into the same directory with your exe. If the latter doesn't work, that's a relevant/important detail, and will lead us down different directions such as those Grantly raises.

(You definitely have a libpq.dll that works somewhere on your system, but if it's a different version that's first in the PATH between the two environments, that's a more interesting issue than the more likely scenario where there's only one DLL, one PATH includes it, the other does not).

I think you might be onto something @CharlesDuffy.  Thanks for this.  Unfortunately I won't be able to test this theory until I am in work tomorrow, but I very much appreciate your time and your patience.

How to debug DLL issues in MinGW?

Many thanks @Charles.  It turned out that it was indeed the PATH that needed to be fixed.  I am not sure if you would like to close/delete this question now.  I would like it to stay since I didn't know enough to be able to find that other answer, and so others may find themselves in the same situation.  But I leave it up to you.

It turned out that the problem was related to the PATH variable.
The executable was successfully linked with a DLL on the search path in MSYS2, but the PATH variable for the system (the one used for the cmd utility) did not include this folder.  Fixing this led to successful execution of the code.

Additional information:
MSYS2 has its own environment variables and a virtualized file system, which is different from regular Windows environment used by CMD. When running programs inside MSYS2, it can automatically find required DLLs because they’re included in it's path.
Solutions:

Add MSYS2 DLL path to Windows PATH If you want your program work in CMD.
Or copy target DLL to executable’s directory If you don’t want to modify the global PATH.
Or use MSYS2 Shell for running your program.

